# Xamarin Android Player Crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I have been trying to get Xamarin Android Player to work for at least two days.  It works for a little bit, then crashes.  It isn't even loading a program.  The device just starts and then crashes instantly.

I opened VM and tried to run it just to see if there were any errors.

These are the errors that I got.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
dev/hw random not found

init property sys.powerctl doesnt exiswt while expanding

powerctl cnanot expand

trying to mount dev/block/sdc

cannot find install-recovery.sh
```

Comment: I would try filing a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Also, what OS version are you running? I know I didn't get it to work on any of the OS X 10.11 betas when it would run just fine on OS X 10.10

Comment: have many problems with Xamarin Player, it never worked for me. Fix one problem another appears. Very bad experience. My OS is Windows 7 professional.

Comment: Any alternate for XAP?

Comment: If you working with Visual Studio try Visual studio Emulator. It works very good for me .